# Ubuntu mate 18.04 - Kivy app working on desktop but not in cli (Unable to find any valuable Windows provider)

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, command-line-interface, raspberry-pi3, ubuntu-18.04

I've written a kivy app taht works perfectly when launched from ubuntu mate desktop via a terminal window. However, if I boot into cli, the app cannot launch because it is unable to "find any valuable Window provider".
The final goal would be to boot directly into the app when the RPi is started. I plan to do that by booting into cli and then launching my app as a service.

I'm running ubuntu mate 18.04 on a raspberry Pi 3B+ and using kivy to create my program. To make sure that the issue did not come from my script I reproduced the issue using the standard Hello world script from kivy.

Here is the code I use:

```
import kivy #added this just in case
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
       return Label(text="Hello World!!!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   SimpleKivy().run()
```

And here is the error I get:

```
(cv) droppi@droppi-desktop:~$ python test.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/droppi/.kivy/logs/kivy_19-07-25_124.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0.dev0, git-Unknown, 20190724
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/droppi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34)
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/home/droppi/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2(['text_pango'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
egl_rpi - ImportError: cannot import name 'bcm'
  File "/home/droppi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 62, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "/home/droppi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from kivy.lib.vidcore_lite import bcm, egl

sdl2 - RuntimeError: b'No available video device'
  File "/home/droppi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 70, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "/home/droppi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 152, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "/home/droppi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 983, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "/home/droppi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 290, in create_window
    self.get_gl_backend_name())
  File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 110, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window
  File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 74, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.die

x11 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.core.window.window_x11'
  File "/home/droppi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 62, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

I assume the issue is linked to the fact that there is no x session active in cli mode but I did not find a way to get only a window provider for my app without going to the desktop first with something like startX.

I guess my question is: How do I make the kivy app launchable from a cli boot?

EDIT:
I had kivy app working before on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 also on raspberry pi (3B, not b+) in cli mode. Both manually launched or from a service but I cannot seem to make it work with the new Ubuntu

Comment: Many times when the script is launched in the boot even the graphical interface does not start so it could generate that problem, a possible solution is to launch the script n seconds (for example 5 seconds) after booting

Comment: Yes I good point. However, the error also appears when I launch the script manually long after the boot sequence has ended

Comment: It looks like Kiwy is a GUI framework. It probably won't work as a headless service at all.

Comment: Thing is, I had it working on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 kind of out of the box and I cannot find what I did differently.
Is is possible to start a window manager/xserver just for my app?

Comment: Kivy gets compiled against a specific window provider when it's installed. To work on an rpi without X, it needs to be compiled against the rpi-specific window provider. Your Kivy probably isn't, it's using sdl2 or x11 instead.

Comment: Ok makes sense. Does that mean that I should reinstall Kivy while in the CLI so that it grabs the window provider that's available in that environment?